Micrsoft Graph : How to make mail Snoozed
I'm trying to create 'snooze' function with outlook using Graph api (or sdk).
If 'snooze' mail with 1 hours later, the mail moves to 'snooze' folder. After 1 hours later the mail is back to inbox mail folder as new mail (this is how snooze work).
I search some properties using MFCMAPI program and found 'SystemTime 0xf07' is added when the mail is snoozed. Therefore, I applied using graph explorer for testing
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages/AAMkAGUyM2ExYmJiLWMzYWItNGI3Ny1iMDU........GIpAAA

{
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "id": "SystemTime 0xf07",
            "value": "2024-04-26T08:45:00Z"
        }
    ]
}

The property is well applied but I wasn't enough for 'snooze' function.
I tried followupflag like bellow body but it's doesn't work too.
{
    "flag": {
        "flagStatus": "flagged",
        "startDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2024-04-29T07:52:00",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "dueDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2024-04-29T07:52:00",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }
}

Anyone know the answer? help me please!

Did you ever manage to build a snooze using MAPI?

What I see in MFCMapi, when follow-up is set in Outlook client, these MAPI properties are added to a message:

PidLidReminderSignalTime
PidLidReminderTime
PidLidReminderSet
PidLidCommonEnd
PidLidCommonStart
PidTagFlagStatus
PidTagFollowupIcon
PidLidTaskStartDate
PidLidTaskDueDate
PidLidTaskComplete
PidFlagRequest
PidLidPercentComplete
PidLidToDoOrdinalDate
PidLidToDoSubOrdinal
PidLidToDoTitle
PidTagToDoItemFlags

You know how to set these properties through the Graph API, so I will share only link to the MAPI doc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-properties
If you will face any issues, it would be useful to share PATCH request body with us. I would recommend to read description for each property, because quite often there are sets of properties mentioned above which must be set together.
